# UIImagePickerController messing tabbar frame when dismissing

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uitabbarcontroller, uiimagepickercontroller

I am trying to show a UIImagePickerController in a UIViewController inside a UITabBarController

SourceType Camera

MediaType kUTTypeMovie

There's no issue presenting the UIImagePickerController, but when dismissed the TabBar moves down half the height, it only happens sometimes... other it dismisses perfectly.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {

    var test: UIButton = UIButton(frame:CGRectMake(140, 200, 100, 100))
    test.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
    test.addTarget(self, action:"presentCamera", forControlEvents: .TouchDown)
    self.view.addSubview(test)
}

func presentCamera(){
    if UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.Camera){
        imag.mediaTypes = [kUTTypeMovie]
        imag.delegate = self
        imag.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.Camera;
        imag.videoQuality = UIImagePickerControllerQualityType.TypeMedium
        imag.videoMaximumDuration = 120
        imag.allowsEditing = false
        self.presentViewController(imag, animated: true, completion:{println("showing")})
    }

}

func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [NSObject : AnyObject]) {
    let library = ALAssetsLibrary()
    var videoTemp = info[UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL] as NSURL
    videoPath = videoTemp.relativePath
    UISaveVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum(videoPath, self, nil, nil)
    picker.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion:{
        println("video selected")
    })    
}

func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(picker: UIImagePickerController) {
    picker.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion:{
        println("canceled")
    })
}
```

It is also displaying this error:

> "Snapshotting a view that has not been rendered results in an empty
>   snapshot. Ensure your view has been rendered at least once before
>   snapshotting or snapshot after screen updates."

Here is a video of how the app and the error looks:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o1BgLbZgsfw

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It was already asked here:

[Redbar Noticed when dismissing UIImagePickerController](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26651355/redbar-noticed-when-dismissing-uiimagepickercontroller?rq=1)

I also noticed the red status bar when dismissing, solved using this:

you should set "View controller-based status bar appearance" value to YES in the .plist